Can any finite topology be "built up" in the way?
Lemma: Let $(Y,\mathfrak{I}')$ be a topological space. Let $A$ be any set, and let $X:= Y\cup A.$ Define the collection $\mathfrak{I}$ of $X$ as the collection of subsets $O$ of $X$ of the form $O = O'\cup A$ for each $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$ Furthermore, let $\emptyset \in\mathfrak{I}.$ Then one can show that $(X,\mathfrak{I})$ is a topological space (although $Y$ is not necessarily a topological subspace of $X$ or vice versa).
Let $X_n:= \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and let $(X_n, \mathfrak{I})$ be a topological space. Let $Y_1\subset X_n$ and $\mathfrak{I}_1: = \{\emptyset,Y_1\},$ so that $(Y_1,\mathfrak{I}_1)$ is a topological space. Then by the lemma above, we may union each member of $\mathfrak{I}_1$ with a set $A_1\subset X_n,$ to create a new topological space $(Y_2,\mathfrak{I}_2),$ where $Y_2 = Y_1\cup A_1,$ and we let $\emptyset\in Y_2$ also. Next, we may union each member of $\mathfrak{I}_2$ with a set $A_2\subset X_n,$ to create a new topological space $(Y_3,\mathfrak{I}_3),$ where $Y_3 = Y_2\cup A_2,$ and we let $\emptyset\in Y_3$ also.
The aim is to do this finitely many times and end up with the topological space $(X_n, \mathfrak{I}),$ in other words, $(Y_k,\mathfrak{I}_k)=(X_n, \mathfrak{I}),$ for some integer $k.$ My question is, is it always possible to do this for any given finite topological space $(X_n, \mathfrak{I})?$

This is not true. Your construction, in case $A$ is nonempty, will yield a topological space in which all nonempty open sets contain a shared nonempty subset, namely $A$. If $A = \varnothing$ instead, then $(X, \mathfrak{I}) = (Y, \mathfrak{I}’)$. Since you start with $(Y_1, \{\varnothing, Y_1\})$, which has the above property, your end result will always have the above property, i.e., all nonempty open sets contain a shared nonempty subset. Thus, if $(X_n, \mathfrak{I})$ does not have the said property, say, if $n \geq 2$ and the topology is discrete, then it cannot be obtained through your proposed procedure.

I feel like there is a variant of my question to which the answer is affirmative, or at least more interesting.

@AdamRubinson Well, instead of letting $\mathfrak{I}$ to only consist of $O’ \cup A$ for $O’ \in \mathfrak{I}’$ (as well as the empty set), you can, instead, ask it to consist of $O’ \cup A$ for $O’ \in \mathfrak{I}’$, and $O’ \cup (O’’ \cap A)$ for $O’, O’’ \in \mathfrak{I}’$. (Note that I’m allowing $Y$ and $A$ to have nonempty intersection.) It’s slightly more annoying, but you can verify that this defines a topology on $X = Y \cup A$. Then the answer is actually affirmative.

Or what if:  Define the collection $\mathfrak{I}$ of $X$ as the collection of subsets $O$ of $X$ of the form $O = O'\cup A$ for each $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$ Furthermore, let $\emptyset \in\mathfrak{I}.$ Furthermore, let $O'\in\mathfrak{I}$ for each $O'\in\mathfrak{I}'.$

@AdamRubinson That’s not a topology in general. If, say $A \not\subset Y$ and $A \cap Y \notin \mathfrak{I}’$, then $A \in \mathfrak{I}$ and $Y \in \mathfrak{I}$, but their intersection is not in $\mathfrak{I}$. (You can instead consider the topology generated by those sets, but that’s exactly the topology I wrote down in my last comment.)
